# How do I practically use the media library?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, media

Now that Drupal 8.6 is released, I tried the experimental *Media Library* module. It works great, but it needs some additions.

How can I use core Media Library with CKeditor?
How can I fill custom fields added to media entities (images) on upload?

I can of course go back to entity embed, entity browser etc, but I wonder if this is already possible through modules or tricks that extend the core Media Library.

Comment: no, you still need to use contrib modules, see this tutorial for D8.5+ https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/

Comment: I don't mind contrib, but I hoped there would be a module that added to Media Library instead of completely replacing it.

Comment: There are plans, but nothing decided yet, see proposed resolution 2. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2801307